# LEGO G-Scale train?

Tags: trains

I have a 45mm gauge LGB-based G-scale garden railway and want my grandson to have a push-along loco and some rolling stock for it.  Can we make this with LEGO? The wheels need to be non-metal and have inner flanges. Apart from the gauge itself, it does not have to be to scale or be highly realistic. At his age, it's the scope for imaginative play with figures and loads that we're after.

Answer (score 5):

The beauty of LEGO is that you can create virtually anything with it. I assume you are aware of the existence of LEGO Trains such as [60052 Cargo Train](http://brickset.com/sets/60052)? The scale of these trains is not directly compatible with LGB's G-scale (the LEGO scale is sometimes referred to as L-Scale or L-Gauge) but many of the train elements can be used for building different scales. More details on the LEGO L-Gauge can be found [here(l-gauge.org)](http://l-gauge.org/wiki/index.php?title=Welcome_to_L-Gauge).

[image]

Some of the train elements you want to take a look at are [Wheels](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?q=Train%20wheel), [Magnetic Couplings](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=73092) and [Axles](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?q=technic%20axle), which form the basis of any train and/or wagon.

[image]
[image]
[image]

You will have to experiment a bit with sizing, e.g. how many bricks wide is G-scale track, and how do flange and thread dimensions of wheels work on G-scale rails. LEGO's assortment of train wheels is limited (only a few sizes), but you might want to check out [Big Ben Bricks' Custom Train wheel collection](http://bigbenbricks.com/products/products.html) for additional sizes.

You are not the first one to attempt this, though, a quick [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=LEGO+G-scale+train) showed several images and videos of LEGO trains running on G-scale track. [Here is one recent video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ZBdGblLI3w) that I found interesting. The [author's website (lgtrains.com)](http://www.lgtrains.com/) has more info on these trains.

Comment: Thanks Phil B.  I found this very useful.  In fact we don't have to worry about setting up track as my garden layout has a convenient siding/loop at a nice height next to a path where he can shunt to and fro.  Main challenge is getting the gauge right, which will obviously depend on getting axles that are long enough, as 'L-scale' seems to be narrower-gauge than our 45 mm set up.  Just wondering though if you know of a good Lego store we can visit in the London area or Derby-Nottingham-Leicester area.

Comment: You can always go to a LEGO store (I'm in the US, but lived in London 15 years ago :) ) or a big toy store (Toys'r'us, Smyths) to get some inspiration, but to get the pieces I mentioned you'd need to buy several sets which will set you back quite a lot of money. It might be easier to visit [Bricklink.com](http://bricklink.com) or [BrickOwl](http://brickowl.com) and buy individual pieces (or get them from the Pick-A-Brick section at [LEGO Shop@Home](http://shop.lego.com). You could use [Lego Digital Designer](http://ldd.lego.com) to mock up some designs first.

Comment: Once again thanks Phil B for taking trouble to help so much. Things have changed so much with Lego from when I used to do (pretty simple) things with my own children.  But also in UK we've lost a lot of good toy and modelling shops from many city areas like London in recent years.  But I think I've located one in a big mall in W London.  (BTW sorry for assuming you might have lived in UK.  I didn't really take in the geographical constituency of this forum when I joined only few weeks ago).